# Generate a number of ranges for a random set of values

Tags: c#, database, random, range

Given a set of random numeric values in a database, how do I generate a limited list of ranges where each range contains at least one value? The ranges should not overlap and ideally have a similar amount of values in them. Ideally their boundaries should also be multiples of 10, 100, 1000 etc...

For example:

```
Values: 100,150,180,300,400,500,600,650,700
results in
4 ranges: 100-180(2), 180-300(1), 300-600(3), 600-800(3)
```

How could this be done in C# or T-SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MS SQL 2005+`:

```
SELECT range, (MIN(getprev) + MIN(value)) / 2 as range_start, (MAX(getnext) + MAX(value)) / 2 AS range_end, COUNT(*) as range_values
FROM (
  SELECT value,
         NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY value ) AS range,
         (
         SELECT TOP 1 value
         FROM values li
         WHERE li.value < lo.value
         ORDER BY
           li.value DESC
         ) AS getprev,
         (
         SELECT TOP 1 value
         FROM values li
         WHERE li.value > lo.value
         ORDER BY
           li.value
         ) AS getnext
  FROM values lo
) vo
GROUP BY range
ORDER BY range
```

In your case:

```
1   100   240   3
2   240   450   2
3   450   625   2
4   625   700   2
```

Comment: You can do this in a stored procedure and call it from LINQ :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume we want ranges with one value in them each:
Values: 100 150 180 300
Just produce these random numbers:

```
- a: 0 <= 100, eg: 50
- b: 100 <= 150, eg: 125
- c: 150 <= 180, eg: 165
- d: 180 <= 300, eg: 200
- e: 300 <=    , eg: 350
```

...

Ranges:
`50-125 (1), 125-180(1), 180-200(1), 200 - 350 (1) ...`: each one contains exactly one number.

Now to have more then one number in each range, just start skippin numbers, for example skip c (can pick a random chance to skip one):
skip c:

```
50-125(1), 125-200(2), 200-350(1)
```

Comment: I'm sure if I get your answer... could you write some pseudo code for your algorithm?

Comment: Looking at this again, this answer misses the point. I already have the values (prices) in the database and want a query to allow the user to be able to drill down into a specific range.